# TinyMCE - pressing tab causes the toolbar to disappear

Tags: extjs, tinymce

We have an Ext JS app with a TinyMCE rich text editor handled by an Ext extension called Ext.ux.TinyMCE.

In firefox (3 and 4) and internet explorer 9 when the text box is focused and the user hits the tab key, the toolbar disappears.

In chrome (11) a tab is inserted.

This behavior cannot be seen on the tiny MCE demo page:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

But is can be seen on the Ext.ux.TinyMCE page:
http://blogs.byte-force.com/xor/tinymce/

Anyone have a fix, or a suggestion as how to fix this?

**Update**

Following the helpful comment by @XOR I started looking at things that could receive the focus of a tab. We are not displaying the status bar but I checked to see if a hidden status bar could still receive focus. I don't think this is the case.

What does appear to be receiving focus is a curious anchor tag at the end of the table which represents the control.

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

When I delete this through firebug the tab no longer hides the toolbar. However removing this programmatically would just be a workaround, the main problem (again pointed out by @XOR) is the height of the control compared to its container. It seems like there are either some resizing conflicts or layout problems afoot here.

Comment: Chris, do you have some sort of test page that showcases this behavior? I tried my demos now and see that toolbar disappears when editor doesn't fit in its paceholder fully. In this case tab positions you to the status bar of the editor which is covered under the cut. Status bar got scrolled into view, while toolbar got hidden.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that you've now fixed it now on that page and the explanation makes sense, however we've got the status bar location set to "none". How can we ensure the editor fits the placeholder?

Comment: Chris, try to make a standalone test page and I will look at it. Editor must fit into a placeholder, but there is some tricky bug that sometimes prevent it from correct behavior.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.witzelsucht.co.uk/codetest/testmce.html it's pretty clear this is the anchor setting that's causing the problem. Simply removing it is fine for this example but I cannot do that in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to fix this is to comment out the resize code in the Ext.ux.TinyMCE extension. Resizing still seems to work without this code suggesting there is a conflict between the Ext, TinyMCE and extension resizing code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following (catch keyboard event and handle the insertion of the tab yourself + disabling of the default browser behaviour). You may use this code inside your own plugin or using the tinymce init parameter setup

```
ed.onKeyPress.add(function(ed, evt) {

  // Tab is pressed
  if (evt.keyCode == 9 && !evt.ctrlKey)
  {

    // check, whether the cursor is inside of a list or not
    var range = ed.selection.getRng();
    var rangeStartNode = range.startContainer;

    /*
    Check if the selcted range is sourrounded by a list
    node, because inside a listing the TAB key should have
    it's original function (indent or outdent (shift))
    */
    if (!t.isSurroundedBy(rangeStartNode, 'LI') && !t.isSurroundedBy(rangeStartNode, 'UL') && !t.isSurroundedBy(rangeStartNode, 'OL') && !t.isSurroundedBy(rangeStartNode, 'TD') && !t.isSurroundedBy(rangeStartNode, 'TH'))
    {
        if (is_win && evt.shiftKey || mac && evt.altKey)
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&#x21e5;'); // insert right-indent tab entity
        else
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&#x2192;'); // insert normal tab entity
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a definite last resort. I like the behavior in chrome and I wouldn't want to stop that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in the Ext.form.CompositeField control that you use in your example. Ext.ux.TinyMCE is not receiving a call to onResize method when parent composite field got resized by anchor layout. So the editor doesn't have a chance to change its size.

If you would remove CompositeField and place editor right into the form, then resizing works correctly. Even with anchor layout.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Firstly this seems a little contrary to what I found. If I disable the Ext.ux.TinyMCE resize code the problem goes away. Or am I missing something? Secondly the example is a simplification; we have an entity called switchable field that extends the compositefield meaning the user can have view and edit versions. We cannot change the compositefield.